# Can I hide a file or a folder in ubuntu?

Tags: windows

So I have been trying to hide a folder or maybe even a file on Ubuntu.

Please leave an answer and thanks in advance.
PS I'm new to Ubuntu and just switched from windows 10.

Comment: Hide from what?

Answer (score 2):

You can hide files and folders by prefixing their name with a dot